# android widget update text using activity

Tags: android, buttonclick

I want to update widget item when I Add or Remove item using activity in my WelcomeWidget class onReceive() as

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
 setup(context); 
 if (datalist.size() != 0)
 { 
 if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_NEXT_TIP)) {
     mMessage = getNextMessageIndex();
     SharedPreferences.Editor pref = context.getSharedPreferences( 
      PREFS_NAME,            0).edit(); 
     pref.putInt(PREFS_TIP_NUMBER, mMessage); 
    pref.commit(); 
    refresh();
    } 
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SETTING))
     {
     Intent articleIntent = new Intent(context,
     LoremActivity.class);                 
      articleIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(articleIntent);      
  } else {

      refresh();        
  }  }   }
```

where refresh method is as :

```
private void refresh() {

     RemoteViews rv = buildUpdate(mContext); 
     for (int i : mWidgetIds) {
      mWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(i, rv); 
         }
```

> 

Using Animation as :

```
AnimationSet farsiTelLogoAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);
         RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);      
        rotate.setFillAfter(true);     
       rotate.setDuration(1000);
        farsiTelLogoAnimation.addAnimation(rotate);
```

}

getting message index
      private int getNextMessageIndex() {

```
  return (mMessage + 1) % datalist.size();

     }
```

where buildUpdate () method is as

```
     public RemoteViews buildUpdate(Context context) { 

          RemoteViews updateViews =
         new  RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);

    // Action for tap on bubble        
       Intent bcast = new Intent(context,
       WelcomeWidget.class);
       bcast.setAction(ACTION_NEXT_TIP);
        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
          0, bcast, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
      updateViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pending);

       // RemoteViews updateViews1 = new
      RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), // R.id.setting);

       Intent bcast1 = new Intent(context, WelcomeWidget.class);
        bcast1.setAction(ACTION_SETTING);       PendingIntent pending1 =
      PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
          0, bcast1,      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);       
      updateViews.
      setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.setting, pending1);

        // Tip bubble text      if (mMessage >= 0) {            // String[] parts =

     sNewlineRegex.split(mTips[mMessage], 2); 
     String to = datalist.get(mMessage).getFrom(); 
     String from =       datalist.get(mMessage).getTo();
      String rate = datalist.get(mMessage).getRate();

  // Look for a callout graphic referenced in the text            Matcher m =

     sDrawableRegex.matcher(to); 
    if (m.find()) {
      String imageName = m.group(1);
      int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(

      imageName, null, context.getPackageName());
      // updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.tip_callout, resId);
      // updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tip_callout,
      // View.VISIBLE);
      to = m.replaceFirst("");            } else {
      // updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.tip_callout, 0);0
      // updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tip_callout, View.GONE);          }

    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.to, to);
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.from, from);
    updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.rate, rate);
    updateViews.setTextViewText(
          R.id.tip_footer,
          context.getResources().getString(R.string.pager_footer,
                  (1 + mMessage), datalist.size()));              
             updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tip_bubble, View.VISIBLE);   

            }
           else { 
                  updateViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.tip_bubble, View.INVISIBLE);
               }

           return updateViews;    

          }
```

where Button click event reload widget

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your code because the format is horrible.

Anyway, to update a widget from your activity you can send a Broadcast intent with APPWIDGET_UPDATE. Use the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourWidgetProvider.class);
intent.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
int ids[] = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplication()).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(getApplication(), ASquareAnalogClockProvider.class));
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,ids);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Hope it helps :)